# Netbeans - Track time spend in project

Tags: netbeans, time

is there any way, how to track how much time i have spent in every project and after (for example) 5mins of inactivity clocks stop tracking time and resume immediately when i return to computer
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Are you asking how to code this, or is this a solution to time-track yourself?

Comment: That would be great if it exists!

Answer (score 1):

Like this one : 
[image: screenshot]
?

it is for Mac OS X:  TimeTrack

You should search for your platform and must be a native desktop application.
It can be made in C# too for Microsoft Windows.

Comment: No... He's probably talking more like how Eclipse's mylyn plugin can keep track of how long a person has been working on a task.

Answer (score 1):

Try WakaTime Metrics, insights, and time tracking automatically generated from your programming activity.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56647/wakatime